# How to include R in MERN app

Tags: r, node.js, reactjs

I am looking for an easy, yet performant way to include R into a MERN (mongo,express, react, node) app. 
I have researched quite a bit and it seems like that there are many ways to do this. One would be to use the "r-script" npm package.

But I am confused on which approach is the correct one.
The app should do following:

1. User uploads or selects R script on the web page.
2. Makes adjustments to the script (sets parameters etc.)
3. R script runs asynchronously in background
4. output gets sent to user who see the data and plot graphs

Comment: would security be a concern if you allow users to make changes to the R script? you might want to check out `opencpu`.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. From what I saw, in OpenCPU the R files need to be adjusted to their API. This could be useful, but it generates overhead, if I have to change hundreds of different scripts. I would like to call the scripts, run them and see their output on the web app without touching the R scripts